# Rails - How to calculate average in view with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a @shirts variable set in my controller that is an array of all products of a particular Category (so it is @shirts = @category.shirts) in my controller.

Then in my view, I want to be able to calculate the average price of a particular shirt from @shirts based on certain conditions.

So for example, calculate the average price of all shirts where the color is red and the size is small.

I am new to rails so I am not sure if I am taking the right approach. Right now I have in my view:

```
<%= @shirts.average_price("Red","Small") %>
```

In my model:

```
def average_price(color, size)
    self.class.average(:price).where(color: color, size: size)
end
```

Right now I am getting:

```
undefined method `average_price'
```

This aside, is this the best approach to take? There are obviously a number of combinations of sizes and colors and I want to show them all in a table, calculating the average price for each combination. What would be a more DRY way of doing this?

Right now I am manually defining table rows and trying to pass in the conditions for size & color for each row, but the HTMl gets repetitive. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you want `def self.average_price`. I think that solves the error you are getting, but not your question.

Comment: like you said `@shirts variable set in my controller that is an array` and array does not have an average_price method, it looks like you have defined this method on your product model? maybe it should be a class method on product instead - and call it like `Product.average_price...`

Comment: When I change it to def self.average_price I get the error: undefined method `average' for Class:Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def self.average_for(size, color)
  where(color: color, size: size).average(:price)
end
```

You will use it like this:

```
@shirts.average_for('small','red')
```

Your `@shirts` should not be an array, instead a relation:

```
class Category...
  has_many :products # or shirts in your case
```

Comment: If you define it in Product model and Shirt model inherits from Product, you can call method in both classes. I would define it in Product.

Comment: I defined it in Shirt model and got this error: undefined method `default_scoped?' for #<BigDecimal:7fa24b748a98,'0.182E4',9(36)> What does that mean? When I defined it in Product model, I got: undefined method `average_for'

Comment: Seems scope is not the same as defining a class method, try with a class method, let me update